# A linear order that every proper initial segment is $\operatorname{seg}(x)$ for some $x$ is a well-order

Tags: elementary-set-theory, well-orders

Can someone help with the following problem:
Let $\langle A, R\rangle$  is a linear ordered set. Let every time when $w$ is an initial segment of $\langle A, R\rangle$, to be true that $w=A$ or $(∃x ∈ A)(w = \operatorname{seg}(x))$. Prove that $\langle A,R \rangle$ is a well ordered set.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: You start with "*Let <A,R> is a well ordered set*" and end with "*Prove that <A,R> is a well ordered set*"

Comment: Sorry, on the first part should be LINEAR ORDERED set.

Comment: Azriel Levy used to introduce well-orders with an intermediate notion of a "queue" which is a linear order where every tail has a least element, which is exactly the property you describe ($x$ is the least element of $A\setminus w$ if and only if $w=\operatorname{seg}(x)$).

Answer (score 1):

Given a nonempty subset $S$ of $A$, Apply the given assumption to the set $w$ of all strict lower bounds of $S$.