# Totally ordered to well ordered set

Tags: set-theory

**(ZF)** Let *<A, R>* be a totally ordered set. Let every time when *w* is an initial segment of *<A, R>*, is true *w* = *A* or ($\exists$*x* $\in$ *A*)(*w* = seg(*x*)). Prove that *<A, R>* is a well-ordered set.

Because it has to be proven in **(ZF)** I cannot use *Zorn's lemma*.

I know that if *<A, R>* is a well-ordered set, every initial segment *w* is either *w = A* or *w* = seg(*x*) for some *x* $\in$ *A*. But for totally ordered sets that is not always true. For example in the totally ordered set $\mathbb R$ \ {$0$} the initial segment *I* = (-$\infty$, $0$) is not an initial segment *I* $\neq$ seg(*x*) for any *x* $\in$ $\mathbb R$ \ {$0$}.

So in the problem I am guaranteed that for every initial segment of *<A, R>*  the previous scenario doesn't apply. But I am almost completely sure that this does not prove that *<A, R>* is a well-ordered set.

Is there any way of proving that *<A, R>* has a least element so that it is well-orederd? Or any other ideas? [Here I found the same problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3971420/a-linear-order-that-every-proper-initial-segment-is-operatornamesegx-for) but I don't understand the idea that has been given.

Comment: Is $\Bbb Z$ a counterexample of this statement? Every initial segment of $\Bbb Z$ has the form $$\{ y \in \Bbb Z : y \le x \}$$ for some $x \in \Bbb Z$, however $\Bbb Z$ is not well ordered.

Comment: @Crostul In $\mathbb Z$, the empty initial segment is not of the desired form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The counterexample in the comments confuses me, probably one needs the extra assumption that $A$ has a smallest element $a_0$.
I denote the order $R$ by $\le$ and $<$ is understood as usual.

We need to prove that every nonempty subset $S\subset A$ has a smallest element.

Consider $B:=\{a\in A: \forall s\in S.\ a<s\}$.
Note that it's disjoint to $S$.

Then either $a_0\in S$ in which case this is its smallest element, or otherwise $a_0\in B$, so $B$ is a nonempty initial segment.
Since $S$ was nonempty, $B\ne A$, thus by hypothesis $B=\{a:a<x\}$ for some $x\in A$.

Now, clearly for any $s\in S$ we have $s\not<x$ (else we'd get $s\in B$), so $x\le s$ by the order being total.
Finally, $x\in S$ because otherwise $x<s$ would hold for all $s\in S$ and therefore $x\in B$ by definition of $B$, which would imply $x<x$.

Comment: The question assumed that every initial segment has the specified form, not just every nonempty initial segment. The additional information about the empty initial segment provides the first element that you need when$A\neq\varnothing$.